# Listing of MicroBit.h for V1 micro:bit?

Tags: bbc-microbit

I'm looking for a listing of the Microbit.h header file for **V1** microbits.
(Trying to understand a C++ program for controlling the ADC).
I've been able to find the V2 version, but not V1.

Comment: Where did you look? As it appears to be on GitHub and has a tag for v1.0.0-rc1...

Comment: Thanks. I found a lot of .h files in lancaster-university/microbit-dal repo, but not the overall MicroBit.h
Probably the ADC stuff I need will be in one of those files.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here:

https://github.com/lancaster-university/microbit/blob/master/inc/MicroBit.h

The update is dated Nov 23, 2018 which predates v2 of the micro:bit. Good luck with your micro:bit projects.

Comment: [https://github.com/lancaster-university/microbit/blob/v1.0.0-rc1/inc/MicroBit.h](https://github.com/lancaster-university/microbit/blob/v1.0.0-rc1/inc/MicroBit.h) is the version tagged a v1.0.0-rc1